# SSH broken, segfault error 4

Tags: linux, ssh, segmentation-fault

i cannot connect to my server via ssh, it throws me a "server unexpectedly closed connection" after entering the password.

in `var/log/messages` the only noteable message is:

```
Apr 14 17:41:23 s15410270 kernel: sshd[3602]: segfault at c0 ip 7f0801acbdb0 sp 7fff0adff860 error 4 in libc-2.8.so[7f0801a87000+14f000]
Apr 14 17:41:29 s15410270 kernel: sshd[3606]: segfault at c0 ip 7f75f9463db0 sp 7fff027971f0 error 4 in libc-2.8.so[7f75f941f000+14f000]
```

This message appears after a log in attempt via ssh or via sftp

Its a SuSE Linux server.
I'm looking for help where to start to search for the error, i can still act as root via a serial console.

edit: "server unexpectedly closed connection" only appears if i enter the correct password!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure you weren't compromised. Run an rpm verify on your ssh daemon... You may also want to get a tool like `chkrootkit` installed and running.

`rpm -vV openssh | grep 'S\.5'` should work for SuSE. Post the output.

Also see the details posted in: [sshd running but no PID file](https://serverfault.com/questions/364064/sshd-running-but-no-pid-file/364293#364293)

Comment: Thanks!  
S.5.....  c /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
S.5.....  c /etc/ssh/sshd_config  
S.5....T    /usr/bin/ssh  
S.5....T    /usr/sbin/sshd
  
I'll install chkrootkit, rkhunter did run the last on 09'th april and found nothing.

Comment: Your ssh and sshd binaries have been modified. The system has probably been compromised. You can download the `openssh` rpm for your system and force reinstall it by hand (`rpm -ivh --force openssh*rpm`) to get past the initial issue, but you will need to determine the extent of the damage.

Comment: Alright, i'll tell it the guy who is responsible for the servers. Thanks!